# Redirect automatically in a view

Tags: grails, grails-2.3

I'm using Grails 2.3.3. Is there a better way to redirect to another controller/action from a view automatically if specific conditions exist otherwise continue to display the view - rather than doing this in the action itself?

What I am trying to do is prior to a view being displayed I want to check that I am logged in and if not to redirect automatically to the login page without any user intervention.

If I can do it within the view it's easy to add this login check code into the _header.gsp to effect all the pages. This would be much quicker than having to code up each action in each for each view of interest.

Comment: <g:if test="${session.loggedin=='true'}"> do something</g:if><g:else>Do something else</g:else> ... But this is possibly the wrong way of going about it - have a look at filters... https://github.com/vahidhedayati/kchat  take a look here  which I have sort of explained how to expand on filters - this will be grails2 since unsure but don't think filters are currently supported under grails 3.0.X

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do with the help of Grails custom taglib by spitting a javascript code which will redirect page to different URL if you are not logged in. But this will reduce the user experience for those who will be using your product since you are first rendering to this page and then using Javascript, you are redirecting them back to login screen (if not logged in).

I would recommend you another three solutions:

1. Use the Grails's [filters](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters) to protect your actions for authenticated users,
2. You can use custom Java annotations to protect action automatically by writing some bit of code,
3. To skip all the above two solutions, you can make use of a widely used Grails plugin for authentication named [spring security core](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) plugin, which provides the best & easy authentication mechanism and uses the core Spring Java library behind the scene which is in turn a huge and awesome thing to integrate.

Comment: Thanks for all these suggestions. What I've come across is the beforeInterceptor festure which enables you to pass all actions of a controller through an interceptor action prior to viewing.

Comment: Had to redo this comment - could not edit..... Thanks for all these suggestions. What I've come across is the beforeInterceptor feature which enables you to pass all actions of a controller through an interceptor action prior to viewing. It enables me to do checks such as a login check for ALL actions or can filter on specific actions - such as checking users have specific rights to display specific views. Are there any issues I should be aware of using this feature such as it being deprecated in later versions I am using grail 2.3.3?

Answer (score 0):

as easy as to define a simple JS-based redirect in your GSP, or even better in shared template:

```
<sec:ifNotLoggedIn> 
   <g:javascript>
     document.observe( 'dom:loaded', function(){
       document.location = '${createLink( controller:'login', action:'doLogin' )}';
     } );
   </g:javascript>
</sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
```